# longtable- head or foot not at start of table

Tags: longtable

I have a long table producing an error ("head or foot not at the start of table") at the line: `\endlastfoot`.

I can't figure out where is the problem. I will appreciate any insight.

My code is as follow (I cut the number of rows)

```
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|p{}|}
\caption{Title}
\label{}
\\
\hline {d} & {W} & {R} &  {S} & {D} & {C1} & {C2} & {C3} & {A} & {N}\\
\endfirsthead
\hline\multicolumn{11}{|c|}
{{ \tablename \ \thetable{}--continued from previous page}}\\
\hline {d} & {W} & {R} &  {S} & {D} & {C1} & {C2} & {C3} & {A} & {N}\\
\endhead
\hline\multicolumn{11}{|c|}{{continued on next page}}\\
\hline
\endfoot
\hline
0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 &  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \cline{1-11}
1 & 1 & 2.3476 & 1.4393 & 0.1864 &  0.8541 & 0.1459 & 0 & 0 & 0.0267 \\ \hline

\endlastfoot
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
```

The table is still producing error:

```
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|p{}|} 
\caption{}
\label{Spearman and distance correlation}
\\\hline{\small G} & {\small B)} &  {\small B} & {\small S (Group C)} & {\small  D} \\
\endfirsthead
\hline\multicolumn{5}{|c|}
{{ \tablename \ \thetable{} continued from previous page}}\\
\hline{\small G} & {\small B)} &  {\small B} & {\small S (Group C)} & {\small  D} \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{{continued on next page}}\\
\hline
\endfoot
\hline
 TR & & & 0.64711267 & 0.6899505 \\\cline{1-5}
        CGR & 0.6605117 & 0.67962766 & &  \\\cline{1-5}
        C2 & 0.60588574 & 0.58207303 & &\\ \cline{1-5}
        C1 & 0.7528371 & 0.75355834 & 0.8530607 & 0.82074517 \\\cline{1-5}
        C2 & & & 0.65749854 & 0.63852245\\ \cline{1-5}
        CR & & & 0.61507607 & 0.63170303\\ \cline{1-5}
        IA1 & 0.56433934 & 0.5921317 & &\\ \cline{1-5}
        IR & 0.84881425 & 0.8601397 & & \\ \cline{1-5}
        I& 0.8097711 & 0.834002 & &\\ \cline{1-5}
        HSD17B1 vs IGF1R & 0.68974805 & 0.7168968 & & \\\cline{1-5}
        HGR & 0.62358147 & 0.6271943 & & \\\cline{1-5}
        HX & & & 0.61812353 & 0.65268934\\ \cline{1-5}
        H3 & & & 0.8229002 & 0.8185904 \\ \cline{1-5}
        R53 vs BCL2 & & & 0.6216794 & 0.6829379\\ \cline{1-5}
        RR & & & 0.6528702 & 0.69094443\\\cline{1-5}
        R3 vs LHCGR & 0.6127419 & 0.6288637 & 0.7181227 & 0.6854638\\\cline{1-5}
        C & 0.8374688 & 0.8288982 & & \\ \cline{1-5}
        R & 0.8382382 & 0.85765386 & & \\ \cline{1-5}
        B2 & 0.8405463 & 0.80230945 & & \\ \cline{1-5}
        FX & 0.71343875 & 0.7239513 & & \\ \cline{1-5}
        F1 & 0.7648222 & 0.7616126 & 0.5658618 & 0.65824085\\ \cline{1-5}
        R & 0.8428854 & 0.8250908 & & \\ \cline{1-5}
      \endlastfoot
      \end{longtable}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Delete the blank line before `\endlastfoot`. If that does not help please make your given code snippet compilable resulting in your issue. Then we can copy the code and test on our computers and play with it to find the error ...

Comment: you have no actual table here just head and foot with no body? also never put `longtable` in a `center` environment (it does not center it, it just adds spurious vertical space)

Comment: Even without correcting the errors Kurt and David told you, your code snippet, completed with a document class and loading `longtable`, gives no error to me: https://v2.overleaf.com/read/jfdthhhvpnby

Comment: Hello, thank you all for your comments. I followed the link  v2.overleaf.com/read/jfdthhhvpnby and to my surprise, I did not see any error. The only difference was that I removed many rows which I have in my table (I don't have an empty line between the last row with numbers and \endlastfoot command in my original table. I've deleted begin{center} but it didn't help. I put below full example.

Answer (score 1):

- in your table code snippet you have `\endlastfoot` on the end of table. correct is after `\endfoot`
- you have defined 6 columns, but use only 5 (sixth not harm, however its definition `p{}` is wrong, you need to specify width of this column, for example `p{1em}`)
- since your table in columns 2 - 5 contains only numbers i suggest to use `S` column type defined in the `siunitx` package
- instead `\cline{1-5}` in table width 5 columns you can use simpler/shorter `\hline`:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{makecell,   % new, for \thead
              longtable}
  \renewcommand\theadfont{\small}
  \usepackage{siunitx}
  \begin{document}
      \begin{longtable}{|c|*{4}{S[table-format=1.8]|}}    % p{1pt}|
  \caption{caption}
  \label{Spearman and distance correlation}                                       \\
      \hline
  \thead{G} & {\thead{B)}} & {\thead{B}} & {\thead{S (Group C)}} & {\thead{D}}    \\
      \hline
  \endfirsthead
      \hline
  \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{ \tablename \ \thetable{} continued from previous page}    \\
      \hline
  \thead{G} & {\thead{B)}} & {\thead{B}} & {\thead{S (Group C)}} & {\thead{D}}    \\
      \hline
  \endhead
      \hline
  \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{continued on next page}                                    \\
      \hline
  \endfoot
      \hline
  \endlastfoot
  TR  &               &               & 0.64711267& 0.6899505     \\  \hline
  CGR & 0.6605117     & 0.67962766    &           &               \\  \hline
  C2  & 0.60588574    & 0.58207303    &           &               \\  \hline
  C1  & 0.7528371     & 0.75355834    & 0.8530607 & 0.82074517    \\  \hline
  C2  &               &               & 0.65749854& 0.63852245    \\  \hline
  CR  &               &               & 0.61507607& 0.63170303    \\  \hline
  IA1 & 0.56433934    & 0.5921317     &           &               \\  \hline
  IR  & 0.84881425    & 0.8601397     &           &               \\  \hline
  I   & 0.8097711     & 0.834002      &           &               \\  \hline
  HSD17B1 vs IGF1R
      & 0.68974805    & 0.7168968     &           &               \\  \hline
  HGR & 0.62358147    & 0.6271943     &           &               \\  \hline
  HX  &               &               & 0.61812353& 0.65268934    \\  \hline
  H3  &               &               & 0.8229002 & 0.8185904     \\  \hline
  R53 vs BCL2
      &               &               & 0.6216794 & 0.6829379     \\  \hline
  RR  &               &               & 0.6528702 & 0.69094443    \\  \hline
  R3 vs LHCGR
      & 0.6127419     & 0.6288637     & 0.7181227 & 0.6854638     \\  \hline
  C   & 0.8374688     & 0.8288982     &           &               \\ \hline
  R   & 0.8382382     & 0.85765386    &           &               \\ \hline
  B2  & 0.8405463     & 0.80230945    &           &               \\ \hline
  FX  & 0.71343875    & 0.7239513     &           &               \\ \hline
  F1  & 0.7648222     & 0.7616126     & 0.5658618 & 0.65824085    \\ \hline
  R   & 0.8428854     & 0.8250908     &           &               \\
  \end{longtable}
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

Comment: Not really. It puts tablenotes to the the wrong row.

Comment: @FinleyHuaxin,  this table doesn't contain table notes. How then is your comment related to to my answer?

Comment: Sorry, I debug the placement of my footnotes and found this change puts it to the wrong place. I didn't notice you do not have table notes.